# embed boostrap into another theme

Tags: bootstrapping

could someone answer this question for me please

I will sound a bit simple, but if you'd had the past week, actually two weeks, that I've had with this client, you would understand..
so here is the simple question, can I incorporate bootstraps features into a preset, non-responsive theme.  here are the details
took on new client who has a site where the front-end was not completed.  They have a custom app that they are basically encasing in drupal. It's a codeIgniter custom application and they got all of that working inside of drupal so it looks like it was drupal created instead of outside/external application; and the theme chosen for for the site is the Business theme [can be found here:  ].

Here is where I come in--  once they got their custom app and drupal to play together, they starting looking into all the other features of drupal itself and decided to move their entire company site into drupal.  Now, I don't know why the original developers didn't pick a responsive theme to work with, assuming they were trying to find something simple that would wrap nicely around this custom app, anyway, in discussions, I can tell, no, I know, the client is going to want the cool responsive "stuff" that comes with bootstrap and with drupal the obvious choice is bootstrap theme.

Since I am just starting the job and am not a themer, more a programmer, I don't want to risk just dumping/disabling the "Business theme", installing and setting up Bootstrap, then configuring it to work around this custom app, I want to know -- can I install bootstrap, the library, not the theme, and then use it in my site as needed, it, along with views_bootstrap, carousel_bootstrap.. all the bootstrap stuff?  Seems like the answer would be yes, but again, you just don't know what these last two weeks have been like moving stuff from one server to another.

so here is what, on a very high level, I am thinking I'll need to do in the not too distant future, create new pages/nodes, add panels, views, etc and I want to be able to use bootstrap with these..  Of course I know you can almost literally do anything, but want to know how feasible and will anything blowup in my face later going this route

Comment: Yes, you can use parts of GPL theme in another GPL theme. But no, we cannot do it for you. It is big and laborious task.

Comment: Reaching back to answer this one.  not sure what you meant by "But no, we cannot do it for you. It is big and laborious task." I don't think anyone is everything asking for someone to do their work for them, but to provide suggestion and insight.

Comment: This site is not a forum. It is for answers, not suggestions and thoughts about. If you want informal discussion, you can find Drupal forums. Official one is here: https://www.drupal.org/forum

Comment: Since I don't have any details about your site or your theme all I can do is guess here, but my guess is that making some sort of hybrid theme may be more troublesome than either making the current theme responsive and ignoring bootstrap all together or ditching your current theme and creating a new one with bootstrap. - The key part here though is that we know nothing of your app, site or theme so we can't give reliable advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i ended up doing and it is working, but the true answer will be to strip out this original theme and start it from scratch with bootstrap, but due the time constraints, that is not an option right now, so what I did was:
Each page/node that you create, includes a unique class name, in addition to the class drupal provides, I created one or two more and each page that I created, I referenced it in my stylesheet, thus forcing my other pages to use the style I wanted.